# Updating React useState object efficiently

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the Material UI Accordian (controlled example from the docs) and I want all the panels open by default. I've been able to achieve this by creating a state object as below. However, I think my method for updating the state on handleChange is clunky.

Is there a better way to write this?

```
  const [state, setstate] = useState({
    panel1: true,
    panel2: true,
    panel3: true,
    panel4: true,
  });

  const handleChange = (panel: string) => (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, isExpanded: boolean) => {
    switch (panel) {
      case "panel1":
        setstate({ ...state, panel1: state.panel1 ? false : true });
        break;
      case "panel2":
        setstate({ ...state, panel2: state.panel2 ? false : true });
        break;
      case "panel3":
        setstate({ ...state, panel3: state.panel3 ? false : true });
        break;
      case "panel4":
        setstate({ ...state, panel4: state.panel4 ? false : true });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array instead:

```
const [panels, setPanels] = useState(new Array(4).fill(true));
const handleChange = (panelIndex: number) => () => {
  const newPanels = [...panels];
  newPanels[panelIndex] = !newPanels[panelIndex];
  setPanels(newPanels);
};
```

Then use, eg, `handleChange(0)` and `handleChange(2)` instead of `handleChange('panel1')` and `handleChange('panel3')`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, where `panel in state` is replacement for `default` in `switch..case`

```
const [state, setstate] = useState({
  panel1: true,
  panel2: true,
  panel3: true,
  panel4: true
})

const handleChange = (panel: string) => (
  event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>,
  isExpanded: boolean
) => {
  panel in state &&
    setstate(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [panel]: state[panel] ? false : true
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only use Controlled mode for toggle open/close, you can extends default Accordion to new component. Bring open/close state to it own state.

```
const NewAccordion = ({ initialOpen = true, ...restProps }) => {
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(initialOpen)
    const toggle = (event, isExpaneded) => setOpened(!isExpaneded)
    return (
        <Accordion expanded={expaneded} onChange={toggle} {...restProps} />
    )
}
```

In case you still want to use Object, just override state of current panel. No need to use switch case

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    panel1: true,
    panel2: true
})
const handleChange = (panel) => (event, isExpaneded) => setState(prev => ({ ...prev, [panel]: !isExpaneded }))

// render
<Accordion expaneded={state.panel1} onChange={handleChange('panel1')} />
```